# How to update child LWC when common attribute between aura parent and child LWC is updated from aura end

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I have an parent aura component for Case List, which is using child LWC component to show list of cases using iteration in lwc.

So an attribute named CaseList is generated at parent aura component via complex business logic and passed in to LWC @api CaseList. Using this @api variable LWC is simply displaying in proper UI format.

Problem is on first load list is properly getting loaded, but when some filter values are updating the CaseList LWC component is not automatically updating at child LWC.

Please help here, any inputs here will be appreciated.

Child Cmp: - cpl_caseListLWC

```
<template for:each={caseRecords} for:item="caseItem">
  <article key={caseItem.Id} class="slds-card slds-m-top_x-small">
            {caseItem.Subject} - Getting iterated 
  </article>
</template>
```

cpl_caseListLWC.js: has a @api variable

```
@api caseRecords;
```

at parent

```
<aura:attribute name="caseRecords" type="List" />
<c:cpl_caseListLWC caseRecords="{!v.caseRecords}" />
```

caseRecords - in aura getting loaded from case list data from salesforce

at initial load child list is getting iterated and rendered fine but when it is changed in aura child list remain as is and not getting rendered automatically.

Comment: Without some code, I'm afraid we can't help you. This sounds like many of the [questions we've had before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=track+lwc+parent+child). Have you tried searching through those? Which ones? If you've tried other solutions, why doesn't it work? The more information you give us, the better we can help you. Please read about [ask] for more information as well.

Comment: I have added some pseudo code for the scenario.was not able to save the tags.

Comment: In the future, use the `{}` code formatter button to preserve code correctly in your question.

Comment: I see no reason here why this wouldn't work, unless there was something off with your JavaScript controller in Aura.